# Connection pooling on a Tomcat 7

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, connection-pooling, tomcat7

I am having issues with implementing connection pooling on a tomcat7.
For some reason tomcat is trying to connect with my machines username. I have been googlin it for a while now but without a luck.

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory 
(FATAL: role "caspinol" does not exist)
Cant connect to db
Log In failed: An Exception has occurred! java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)...
```

My context.xml looks as follows:

```
<Resource auth="Container" name="jdbc/postgres" type="javax.sql.DataSource" user="biller" password="biller" 
            driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432" maxActive="150"
            schema="biller" maxIdle="4"/>
```

And the web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>postgreSQL Datasource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/postgres</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

I am using jdbc4.jar postgres driver.
I appreciate if somebody can have a look and point out what is the mistake

Thanks in advance

Comment: username="biller" rather than user="biller" ?

Comment: Thanks very much. This solved the first problem... strange, this configuration comes actually from "Tomcat - The Definitive Guide". Beware of the books...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL seems to be wrong.
Try this  URL :

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<db_name>
```

Replace the `<db_name>` with actual database name.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right solution here for the issue but would help somebody searching with the same issue with correct connection string.

Check for your network connection access:
Like connection string

```
jdbc:postgresql://[::1]:5432/<db_name>
```

uses IPv6,
This will break other connections like accessing wsdl urls from application that are available  only via IPv4.
Please hava a look on network connection especially windows 8.